# Using a `redirect` with `setpriv` to a file with restrictions

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I want to write a file `my_file.txt` using `echo` within my bash script. The file has the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 snap_daemon root 4096 Apr 11 15:56 my_file.txt
```

How can I use `setpriv` in conjunction with `echo "thing" > my_file.txt` to give me the correct permissions to write to my file?

I was thinking I could do:

```
sudo setpriv \
  --clear-groups \
  --reuid snap_daemon \
  --regid snap_daemon -- \
  echo "thing" > my_file.txt
```

This outputted:

```
-bash: my_file.txt: Permission denied
```

So `setpriv` only applied to the `echo` command, not the redirect to another file. How can I apply set priv to the redirect of the output to `my_file.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: to nest the whole redirection line in a setpriv shell:

```bash
sudo setpriv \
    --clear-groups \
    --reuid snap_daemon \
    --regid snap_daemon -- \
    bash -c 'echo "thing" > myfile.txt'
```